# Maven Integration for RAD7.5 along with automatic Websphere compatible EAR creation

Tags: maven, websphere, ear, ibm-rad, maven-ear-plugin

I want to understand the entire process for integrating Maven with RAD Version 7.5 and creation of the EAR file using maven.

I have been able to successfully integrate Maven with RAD 7.5 using. I also integrated maven-ear plugin with my maven project and I can create the EAR using mvn package command from Run Configurations. However, that EAR cab not be deployed to Websphere Application Server.

So, what I want to understand is:

Is there a way to create an EAR that can be deployed to Websphere Application Server using Maven and RAD 7.5? Please note that I do not have any EJBs in my project.

I was trying to search for this in various forums and I found some answers like one has to add some ibm specific elements to the EAR. If someone can provide specific steps for doing so, it would be really helpful.

Thanks,
Varun.

Answer (score 2):

Try this... but it's not a full answer.  The issue is that Maven and the RAD way of things aren't aligned.  It's 2 different philosophies.  Another thing you might also want to use is the RAD Build Utility (for CI), the Software Analyzer feature in RAD (code quality) and the Code Coverage feature in RAD.

---

Java EE development using Rational Application Developer 7.5.5 and Maven - Learn how the powerful open Maven build framework can be integrated with Rational Application Developer 7.5.5's rich set of Java EE 5 development tools.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/download/attachments/113607155/RAD_755_MAVEN_0601.pdf?version=1

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to find the answer to this question as well.  I read the pdf that the post above references, but it does not solve my problem.  Looks like that document was written a few years ago.  I came across this IBM forum post, which suggests the same problem has been discussed since 2006:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14486753 .  I have not been able to find any information that suggests this problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reconcile the differences between Maven and RAD for quite some time on RAD 8.0.3, with little success.

My personal solution was to create a new Enterprise Application Project solely for development purposes within RAD.  That way you don't need to modify your existing structure to accommodate RAD.