# How to do websphere 7 deployment automation using maven?

Tags: maven, deployment, websphere, websphere-7

Hi all 
Our Maven scripts are currently written to compile/package & deploy in tomcat6 (development) server. This helped us in automating the build-deploy process.

Moving forward, we want to do **automated deployments into WAS7 (Websphere 7) server using MAVEN** scripts. Few articles which i read talks about invoking ANT Tasks that could perform deployment to websphere.

Could anybody share maven scripts/tags for the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if that works for WAS 7, but IBM provide support for WAS 6 and Maven integration  :

- http://sdudzin.blogspot.fr/2007/09/maven-2-and-websphere-automated-build.html
- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/download/attachments/113607155/RAD_755_MAVEN_0601.pdf?version=1
- [Maven Integration for RAD7.5 along with automatic Websphere compatible EAR creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972880/maven-integration-for-rad7-5-along-with-automatic-websphere-compatible-ear-creat)
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14486753

A (famous) French IT consulting company list compatibilities with the well known **Cargo plugin**, that allow remote control on servers : http://blog.xebia.fr/2008/11/05/lintegration-continue-avec-cargo/. But as you can see (even you don't understand french ;D), Websphere is not yes well supported.

It won't probably help you, but the main idea is Maven and WAS 7 integration will probably more painful for you that other servers ;)

Comment: Open the cargo plugin link into Google chrome, and convert it from french !

Answer (score 2):

You can use this plugin 
http://code.google.com/p/websphere-maven-plugin/

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>Websphere7AM.plugin</groupId>
 <artifactId>websphere7am-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0</version>
 <configuration>
  <defaultCommand>
  <host>localhost</host>
  <port>8880</port>
 </defaultCommand>
 <commands>
  <command>
   <command>INSTALL</command>
   <appName>My Application</appName>
   <earFile>myapp.ear</earFile>
   <target>WebSphere:cell=myhostNode01Cell,node=myhostNode01,server=server1</target>
   <description>Install my app</description>
  </command>
 </commands>
</configuration>
<executions>
 <execution>
 <phase>compile</phase>
 <goals>
  <goal>was</goal>
 </goals>
 </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```